# Convert numbers from sqlite to date in Python

Tags: python, date, dataframe

I just downloaded a `csv` from sqlite with a column containing dates. The `df` looks like this:

```
ROWID   text    is_from_me  handle_id   date
8       Esta muy    0       4           542735636047925696
9       Congratz    0       4           542735642840117952
10      En la       0       4           542735660785415872
11      Liked       1       4           542735693412165376
```

How do I turn the `date` column into readable dates?

Comment: Are those numbers real examples? They look too large to be timestamps.

Comment: Yes @Bemmu , they are real examples. I downloaded texts from iMessage (iOS) and that was the timestamp that came with it.

Comment: Can you find out what they represent?  E.g. are they milliseconds since epoch?

Comment: @user9074332 this is what I've found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832714/18-digit-timestamp  Don't know how to do it in Python tho...

Comment: Even for milliseconds since epoch they are too big. For example 542735636047925696/1000 is still in the year 17200577.

Comment: Maybe the date/time was stored in a ```long int``` representation of a TAI64 date format.

Comment: More info here: https://cr.yp.to/libtai/tai64.html

Comment: I tried decoding one using tai64n library, but t.decode_tai64n(hex(542735636047925696)) would have resulted in some year before epoch.

Comment: Looks like they are expressed in nanoseconds. Here is what I got  from ```datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(542735636047925696/1000000000)```: 
 ```datetime.datetime(1987, 3, 14, 12, 53, 56, 47926)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the first 9 digits may represent seconds since 2001-01-01 00:00:00.

```
import time, datetime
t = time.gmtime(int("542735636047925696"[0:9])+978307200)
timestamp = time.mktime(t)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)    
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

# 2018-03-14 15:53:56
```

Based on [Parsing "date" field of iPhone SMS file from backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746562/parsing-date-field-of-iphone-sms-file-from-backup)

Comment: This is of enormous help!! Any way I can convert the output to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ?

Comment: I'll try to see if you'll accept my answer first :-)

Comment: Edited to include converting to timestamp and from there to datetime

Comment: Very much appreciated! You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, I adjusted mine just to have another way registered here. :-)

```
from datetime import datetime

# 1970-01-01 00:00:00
unix_epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

# 2001-01-01 00:00:00   
mac_epoch = datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

# 1s = 10e9 ns
ns = 10**9

date = datetime.fromtimestamp(542735636047925696/ns) + (mac_epoch - unix_epoch)

print(date)

>>> 2018-03-14 15:53:56.047926
```